# Test SNMP Community String on printers

Tags: powershell, snmp

In the company where I work we have different `SNMP Community Names` in use for printers. Most of them have the standard value `public` and are perfectly readable, others have something else like `foo` or `bar`.

The problem is that my PowerShell code doesn't throw an error when the connection part fails. So I can try one of the other `SNMP Community Names`.

Ideally, if the connection fails with all known passwords, I want it to end up in the `Catch` clause, so I know we couldn't connect.

The code:

```
$CommunityName = 'public' # public foo bar
$P = 'PrinterPort'

$SNMP = New-Object -ComObject olePrn.OleSNMP 

Try {
    # There's no error thrown when it can't connect here:
    $SNMP.Open($P,$CommunityName,2,3000)
}
Catch {
    $Global:Error.Remove($Global:Error[0])
    [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        SNMP_PortHostAddress = $P
        SNMP_Status          = "SNMP Connection failed"
    }
}

$SNMP.Get('.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1')

$SNMP.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `$SNMP.Get` command throws an error, so this works fine:

```
$CommunityName = 'public' # public foo bar
$P = 'PrinterPort'

$SNMP = New-Object -ComObject olePrn.OleSNMP 

Try {
    $SNMP.Open($P,$CommunityName,2,3000)
    # Check if connection is successfull:
    $SNMP.Get('.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0') | Out-Null
}
Catch {
    $Global:Error.Remove($Global:Error[0])
    [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        SNMP_PortHostAddress = $P
        SNMP_Status          = "SNMP Connection failed"
    }
}
```